# Override plugin constant using a theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, constants

I have a plugin which starts:

```php
<?php
define( 'MAX_THINGS', 30 );
```

I would like to change the constant to be 2.

I know I can edit the plugin file directly - but that will be overwritten if the plugin is updated.

In my theme's `functions.php` I have:

```
<?php
function my_theme_setup() {
    @define( 'MAX_THINGS', 2 );
```

But that doesn't change things. I assume because the plugin is loaded before the theme?

Is there any way to set a constant *before* the plugin loads?

Comment: Can you check if the constant is always accessed directly (e.g. `$something = MAX_THINGS;`) or indirectly (e.g. `$something = apply_filter('awesome_max_things', MAX_THINGS);`)?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to replace it at all if the plugin is not checking whether the constant has already been defined using `if ( defined( 'MAX_THINGS' ) )`. By definition constants can't be overwritten, so this check is necessary to make a value 'pluggable'. Adding `@` to `define()` will suppress the error but it won't make it work.

As you've noticed, plugins load before themes, so if the plugin *does* include this check you will need to set the constant in either a [Must-use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) or the wp-config.php file, since both are safely editable and load before regular plugins. In my experience if a plugin supports customisation via constants then the expectation is usually that it would be added to wp-config.php.